# Not stopping at the x coördinate

Tags: java, testing, if-statement, while-loop

I am making something with a block that moves, until it hits the x=11 coördinate. I tried doing a while loop within a while loop:

```
public void run() {
    x = 200;
    y = 200;
    while (true) {
        if (left == true) {
            x -= 5;
            while (true) {
                if (x == 11) {
                    left = false;
                }
            }

        }
        if (up == true) {
            y -= 5;
        }
        if (right == true) {
            x += 5;
        }
        if (down == true) {
            y += 5;
        }
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't stop at x = 11 it continues to run indefinitely.
Does anyone know how else i could do this?

Comment: Properly formatted (i.e. indented) code goes down a lot better on stack overflow

Comment: Also; define doesn't work, runs forever? because thats what I would expect

Comment: @RichardTingle what define?

Comment: As in whats the actual problem, doesn't work could be anything from crashes the computer to gives the wrong answer

Comment: In the inner loop use `while (left)` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your block not to move below x = 11. In that case try:

```
    if (left == true) {
        if(x - 5 < 11){
            x = 11;
        }
        else{
            x -= 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No thanks. On other websites I NEED to mention that it is solved, but no not here... -.-

Comment: @TeunissenStefan No problem, stack overflow isn't the usual help forum, its a Q&A site, the primary goal is to generate useful questions and answers that will be of benifit to lots of people. You getting your problem solved is a happy additional benifit, but not the primary goal. Thanking people is always appreciated though

Answer (score 1):

Any program with

```
while(true){
     //any code that coesn't contain break
}
```

will run forever

Each time round the loop it will execute the code in the loop, then return to the line `while(true)`, if the condition is still true (which it clearly will be, being `true` it will go back around again.

These sorts of loop (occasionally) have legitimate usages but must contain `break;` somewhere in the loop to exit them.

In your case both loops have this problem but the inner loop is the one it actually gets stuck in

```
  while (true) {
     if (x == 11) {
         left = false;
     }
  }
```

Stepping though it:

1. Is true==true --> yes, enter loop
2. Is x == 11 --> lets say yes so;
3. set left to false;
4. Is true==true --> yes, enter loop
5. Is x == 11 --> lets say yes so;
6. set left to false;
7. Is true==true --> yes, enter loop

And round and round again

You've stated that you want something to move down (by 5) unless its below 11, the following will achieve this

```
while (x>11){
    x-=5;
    if (x<11){
       x==11;
    }
}
```

This is somewhat inefficient but I’m assuming its a simplification of a more complex problem

Comment: Forever? what if i shut down javaw.exe?

Comment: Unless it has `break` or `System.exit` somewhere inside loop or user will close its porcess :). Anyway since you found problem to make answer full some solution would be nice.

Comment: It will keep on going until you physically destroy the computer.

Comment: @TeunissenStefan Well yes if you force the program to end it will end, but it will never end "normally"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yea, typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    boolean isValid=false;

    while(!isValid){
      if(left==true)
       {
        x -= 5;
          if(x ==11)
           {
            left=false;
            isValid=true;
           }
       }
   }
```

If this is the case not knowing your conditions